Steam running reallly slow and asking for packages
Every time I try to open steam on my Ubuntu 22.04 PC, it displays this message:
`Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libegl1:amd64 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:amd64 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:amd64 libgl1:i386 xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk

Press return to proceed with the installation: 
`

If i press enter. this happens:
    .................E: The repository 'https://deb.etcher.io stable Release' does not have a Release file.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libegl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libegl1 set to manually installed.
libgl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libgl1 set to manually installed.
libegl1:i386 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libegl1:i386 set to manually installed.
libgl1:i386 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libgl1:i386 set to manually installed.
libc6 is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.8).
libc6 set to manually installed.
libgbm1 is already the newest version (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2).
libgbm1 set to manually installed.
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2).
libgl1-mesa-dri set to manually installed.
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.8).
libc6:i386 set to manually installed.
libgbm1:i386 is already the newest version (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2).
libgbm1:i386 set to manually installed.
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is already the newest version (23.2.1-1ubuntu3.1~22.04.2).
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 set to manually installed.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  fuse3
Suggested packages:
  xdg-desktop-portal-gnome
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  fuse
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fuse3 xdg-desktop-portal xdg-desktop-portal-gtk
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 1 to remove and 5 not upgraded.
E: Packages need to be removed but remove is disabled.

Press return to continue: 

Pressing enter again gets me into steam, but every game is extremely laggy. Most games crash completely, some run but very slowly and with choppy audio. As far as I can tell it is all the steam games I have doing this. I have already tried sudo apt-get update and sudo apt upgrade. I have also tried installing those packages in terminal but that didn't seem to work.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you.
EDIT: I disable etcher and fixed the E: error on the first line, but nothing else changed.
EDIT 2:
sudo apt-get update output
Hit:1 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Hit:2 https://repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease                     
Hit:3 https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2004/x86_64  InRelease
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease                      
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [128 kB]     
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [129 kB]      
Hit:7 https://linux-clients.seafile.com/seafile-deb/focal stable InRelease     
Hit:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease            
Get:9 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-security InRelease [7,553 B]
Hit:10 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/trebelnik-stefina/lutris/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Get:11 https://esm.ubuntu.com/apps/ubuntu jammy-apps-updates InRelease [7,456 B]
Get:12 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-security InRelease [7,450 B]
Get:13 https://esm.ubuntu.com/infra/ubuntu jammy-infra-updates InRelease [7,449 B]
Fetched 287 kB in 1s (196 kB/s)       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

sudo apt upgrade output
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
#
# OpenSSH CVE-2024-6387 fix is available for all affected Ubuntu releases.
# RegreSSHion: Possible RCE Due To A Race Condition In Signal Handling.
# For more details see: https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-regresshion-security-fix
#
The following packages will be upgraded:
  lutris thunderbird thunderbird-gnome-support thunderbird-locale-en
  thunderbird-locale-en-us
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 standard LTS security updates
Need to get 69.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 52.2 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 thunderbird-locale-en amd64 1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [1,013 kB]
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 thunderbird amd64 1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [67.4 MB]
Get:3 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/trebelnik-stefina/lutris/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 lutris all 0.5.17+git7572-cb8603e1~ubuntu22.04.1 [1,476 kB]
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 thunderbird-gnome-support amd64 1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [8,634 B]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 thunderbird-locale-en-us all 1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 [8,968 B]
Fetched 69.9 MB in 22s (3,223 kB/s)                                            
(Reading database ... 289866 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../lutris_0.5.17+git7572-cb8603e1~ubuntu22.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking lutris (0.5.17+git7572-cb8603e1~ubuntu22.04.1) over (0.5.17+git7570-f4
2546c0~ubuntu22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird-locale-en_1%3a115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04
.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking thunderbird-locale-en (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (1:115
.12.0+build3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird_1%3a115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1_amd64.d
eb ...
Unpacking thunderbird (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (1:115.12.0+buil
d3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird-gnome-support_1%3a115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.2
2.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking thunderbird-gnome-support (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (1
:115.12.0+build3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../thunderbird-locale-en-us_1%3a115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22
.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking thunderbird-locale-en-us (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) over (1:
115.12.0+build3-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up lutris (0.5.17+git7572-cb8603e1~ubuntu22.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-locale-en-us (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Setting up thunderbird-gnome-support (1:115.13.0+build5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...

After this the computer was restarted but there was no change.
EDIT 3:
Output of apt policy fuse:
  Installed: 2.9.9-5ubuntu3
  Candidate: 2.9.9-5ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 2.9.9-5ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status


Seems like a good question to ask on the Steam Support Forum.

I guess I will try that next, but the steam app itself runs fine, the games do not. I have uninstalled steam and several games and reinstalled them to no effect, so I am hoping there is an explanation in the system for the errors.

Fix your sources first to address the E: error. This question is similar to: What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?. Apt can't do anything until you fix that error.

@user535733 the comment from this user is suggesting that this error from your post could be the issue.  https://deb.etcher.io stable Release Is this something you have recently added?

It has been added recently, should I remove it and then run purge?

You should read the link I provided that tells you exactly how to fix it safely.

I'm confused how you have a 22.04 system that doesn't already have fuse3 installed. In jammy fuse is from universe. There must be some history here.

I disabled etcher and it removed the E error line, but everything else is unchanged. I am fixing the computer for my little siblings, so they might have managed to mess stuff up. Steam still opens the terminal prompt and all of the games are laggy. Should I try and install fuse3?

How about showing us the complete output of "sudo apt update"? Edit it into your question please.

Thank you for the update! What are you installing from that focal ppa on your jammy system?

I bet that you got fuse from that focal ppa and that is what is causing your issue. Try an apt policy fuse and put the output in your question. If it comes from that ppa, I suggest you ppa-purge it. The seafile website says the deb version is deprecated anyway.
